# Sharepoint 2013 FederatedAuthentication is null

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, adfs2.0

I am in an environment where we have Sharepoint 2013 being authenticated by an ADFS server. When I log out of adfs, I stay logged in at sharepoint.

It appears my solution is to use FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.SignOut();

However when I try this I get Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: What's your question exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction. I'm trying to get the sign out to work for both adfs and sharepoint. Here is the code i'm using

```
  private void RemoveCookiesAndRedirect()
    {
        string ipUrl = GetIPUrl();
        //if (ipUrl != string.Empty)
        //{
        string replyUrl = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.Url);
        string redirect = ipUrl + "?wa=wsignout1.0&wreply=" + replyUrl;

        try
        {

                FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.SignOut();

                if (Context.Session != null) Context.Session.Abandon();

                Context.Response.Redirect(redirect);
            //}
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LoggingService.LogError("LoginRedirect", ex.Message + " " + ex.InnerException + " " + ex.Data + " ipUrl:" + ipUrl + " redirect:" + redirect);
        }
    }

    private string GetIPUrl()
    {
        IClaimsPrincipal user = Page.User as IClaimsPrincipal;
        if (user == null) return string.Empty;

        string ipUrl = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            string providerName = (user.Identity.Name).Split('|')[1];
            ipUrl = SPSecurityTokenServiceManager.Local.TrustedLoginProviders[providerName].ProviderUri.AbsoluteUri;
        }
        catch
        {
            //TODO:Log it
        }
        return ipUrl;
    }
```

Whenever it gets to FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.SignOut(); it errors out.